# Script not displaying correctly in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using a short JavaScript function that is working correctly in firefox and IE, and not displaying correctly in chrome. 
The function just types a text block across the page. In FF and IE, it types out fine.  In Chrome, it stops partway through and will not finish.

The script is:

```
var index = 0;
var text ='text to get typed goes here';

function type() {
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
    index += 1;
    var t = setTimeout('type()',50);
}
```

And it's getting called on the page by

```
div align="left" class="normtext" id='screen'
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working in chrome?  Thanks.

Comment: You should just open the console in Chrome and see what error kicks back.

Comment: Use setTimeout(type, 50);, as the string parameter calls use disguised eval

Comment: make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/6kjHx/ Using @Misiur suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

Your setTimeout needs a closure because it calls its function within the global/window scope otherwise. That would prevent the function from being recognized as defined in some cases.

Here is working code:

```
var index = 0;
var text ='text to get typed goes here';

function type() {
    if (index < text.length) { // Don't go on typing after finishing.
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
        index += 1;
        var t = setTimeout(function () {
            type();
        },50);
    }
}
type();
```

You can also see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/PF4Tx/